# JSON iteration in node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, loops

```
[
  {
    "Hs": 5,
    "Type": "Support",
    "By": "William Shake the Speare",
    "Product": "SA",
    "Customer": "Huxley",
    "State": "In progress"
  },
  {
    "Hs": 2,
    "Type": "Support",
    "By": "Orwells",
    "Product": "Web",
    "Customer": "Infranet",
    "State": "Closed"
  }]
```

I have many of this objects and need to take Customer and sum (add) all of his "Hs" value. So the final array would be like:

```
[
{
    "Customer" : "Infranet",
    "Total_hs" : "18" 
},
{
    "Customer" : "Huxley",
    "Total_hs" : "11" 
}
]
```

I tried to find out with lodash and node foreach functions but can't, could you help me please? Thanks!

Comment: That is not a JSON, is an Array of Objects. 
**[JSON](http://json.org/)** is an `Object` serialized to a `String`, used as a data-interchange format, e.g.
`"[{ \"id\": 1, \"name\": \"coco\" }]"`

Comment: @jherax: You're assuming he's showing it in a JavaScript program. In a text file or an XHR response, that's what the JSON would look like. There would be no outer quotes or escaped quotes.

Comment: Yes, but inside a text file you won't iterate an array, you must be inside a program that read that data. Also I added the double quote because that is the standard for `String` type, I could use single quote to enclose the object,  but that is not valid in some programming languages.

Comment: @jherax: Yes, but he's showing the actual JSON. It's very rare to hardcode JSON in a JavaScript program. That's the only time it would be as you show it (or with single quotes).  If I do an XHR request to fetch some JSON, its not going to show up with outer quotes and escaping just because I'm in a JavaScript program.

Comment: He said: 
> I tried to find out with lodash and node foreach functions but can't ...
Meaning that is not a JSON, the JSON already should be parsed as a JavaScript Object.

Comment: @jherax: I'm sure it's already parsed in his program. What he's showing in the question is JSON. That's exactly how JSON serialization looks. There's nothing non-JSON about it. It's a perfect, clean example of the serialization. If he had `var my_data = [{...}, {...}, {...}]` in the question, then I would agree.

Comment: @squint http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/ and I recommend read the comments also ;)

Comment: @jherax: I know exactly what JSON is. You're conflating how the OP is talking about his parsed data with the data that he shows in the question. No JavaScript program would have that syntax standalone because it would be useless as it's never referenced. What he shows in the question is his JSON and then what he's referring to is his parsed data. Again, it's a perfect, clean example of JSON data. You're kind of missing the forest here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must make sure you have the input data as a javascript object (so if it is a json string, it will need to be parsed with something like `var items = JSON.parse(input_string)`)

```
var items = [{
  "Hs": 5,
  "Type": "Support",
  "By": "William Shake the Speare",
  "Product": "SA",
  "Customer": "Huxley",
  "State": "In progress"
}, {
  "Hs": 2,
  "Type": "Support",
  "By": "Orwells",
  "Product": "Web",
  "Customer": "Infranet",
  "State": "Closed"
}]
```

... next, create array of summed `Hs` values...

```
var totals = _.reduce(items, function(memo, item) {
  // make sure that the customer is created on the output object, or initialise it to zero
  memo[item.Customer] = memo[item.Customer] || 0;
  // increment the Hs value with the current item's Hs value
  memo[item.Customer] += item.Hs;
  // return the current object for the next iteration of the loop
  return memo;
// pass empty object to initialise reduce
}, {});
```

totals should now have array of objects, with customer name as key, and total Hs as value.

... next, reformat array to match desired data format...

```
var target_array = _.map(totals, function(item, key) {
  return {
    Customer: key,
    Total_hs: item
  }
});
```

... check the out put is correct...

```
console.log(target_array);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Billy & yanana! I'm newbie I came from mongodb world, this mapreduce is similar to aggregation framework, thanks for help! I have learned a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Given the JSON is provided as a JavaScript object (`items` in the sample below):

```
var items = [{
    "Hs": 5,
    "Type": "Support",
    "By": "William Shake the Speare",
    "Product": "SA",
    "Customer": "Huxley",
    "State": "In progress"
  }, {
    "Hs": 2,
    "Type": "Support",
    "By": "Orwells",
    "Product": "Web",
    "Customer": "Infranet",
    "State": "Closed"
}];
var collected = _.map(_.keys(_.grouped(items, "Customer")), function(k) {
  return {
    Customer: k,
    Hs: _.reduce(grouped[k], function(accumulator, v) {
        return accumulator + v.Hs;
      }, 0)
  };
});
```